# Automatically add AD users to linux group

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory, pam

I need to add users to a specific group on Linux automatically to allow running some programs from another user with no password prompt like:

```
su nopswduser -c 'echo Hello'
```

I'm adding group to local users automatically by extending EXTRA_GROUPS parameter in /etc/adduser.conf

Here is my configuration for /etc/pam.d/su for su with no password prompt.

```
auth    [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = nopswduser
auth    sufficient pum_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup nopswduser
```

All it is works well.
**The problem** is that I have a Active Directory users that can login to Linux machine. Domain membership configured by using samba/winbind. /etc/adduser.conf configuration is not working for AD users. I tried to use group mapping like that way:

```
net groupmap add ntgroup="domain users" unixgroup="nopswduser" rid=1234 type=l
```

But it didn't make any sense and when user trying to *su nopswduser* in terminal appears password to prompt.
I tried to configure PAM system to add user to group automatically on login by modifying /etc/security/group.conf with line:

```
*;*;*;Al0000-2400;nopswduser
```

And adding this lines to /etc/pam.d/common-auth and /etc/pam.d/login

```
auth    optional    pam_group.so
```

When I'm login from AD account group appears in *uid* command, but when I'm trying to *su nopswduser* terminal asks for password like user is not in group.

There is no problem when I'm **manually** adding AD user for /etc/group, but I need to do this **automatically** because I don't know who concretely of AD users can login to Linux machine.

There is MX Linux 19.4 running on machine. Domain is controlled by Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Linux computer is domain joined, if so, then you don't map an AD group to a Linux group, you just make the AD group into a Linux group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I mentioned I have local users. And I have suspicions that users won't be able to **su** to another user without password if they are not inside his primary group.